# I need to assign srcObject to itself to get a WebRTC video stream to show up

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc

The setup: I have a C++ program that streams one video stream, using WebRTC (GStreamer-based). On the client side, Chrome (was originally using firefox, but then I figured out that webrtc-internals could be nice to debug the issue).

The app tries to connect repeatedly to the C++ program using WebSocket. Once I get a successful connection, I assign the resulting MediaSource to the video's srcObject property. The result is a blank screen. However, if I get into the console and manually assign the srcObject to itself, that is

```
var elem = document.getElementById("stream0")
elem.srcObject = elem.srcObject
```

the video suddenly appears.

In the code below, the AsyncVideoStream class deals with the overall webrtc connection and reconnection handling. I don't think that it's relevant here, as the chrome webrtc-internals stats show clearly that the webrtc connection is successfully established even when nothing is displayed (I get a decoded fps number that matches the sender's).

The HTML is pretty simple:

```html
<div class="video-stream-container-fullwidth">
    <video class='video-stream' id="stream0" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

The javascript (actually, typescript):

```
import AsyncVideoStream from './video_stream'

var config = { 'iceServers': [] };
var vidstreams = {}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    vidstreams[0] = new AsyncVideoStream('ws://localhost:57000/ws', config)

    var streamer = vidstreams[0];
    var id = `stream0`
    streamer.onVideoStream((stream) => {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id) as any;
        elem.srcObject = stream;
    })
})

document.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    vidstreams[0].dispose();
})
```

Comment: It might be connected with the restricted autoplay policy. Could you try with `<video class='video-stream' id="stream0" autoplay="true" muted="true" playsinline></video>`? The `muted` attribute might be the key.

Comment: It was indeed. Seems that interacting with the console is counted as "user interaction" Just add this as an answer instead ... I can then mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't work because of the restricted autoplay policy.

The following works (muted attribute is the key):

```
<video class='video-stream' id="stream0" autoplay="true" muted="true" playsinline></video>
```

As @sylvain.joyeux found, interacting with the console is counted as "user interaction".