# Multi-stream WebRTC application not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, html5-video

I have a custom WebRTC application that uses two video streams and one audio stream.

Everything is working nicely on Chrome (93.0) and Firefox (92.0), but Safari (14.1) refuses to play one of the streams (the one for the first video element with ID "stream").

HTML looks as follows (mostly placeholders):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>
    <script src="stream.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="display:grid">
      <video style="grid-column:1;grid-row:1;width:720px;z-index:5" id="stream" autoplay playsinline>Your browser does not support video</video>
      <canvas style="grid-column:1;grid-row:1;justify-self:end;width:1280px;height:720px;z-index:10" id="canvas"></canvas>
      <video style="grid-column:1;grid-row:1;justify-self:end;width:1280px;height:720px" id="stream2" autoplay playsinline>Your browser does not support video</video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The relevant part of the Javascript code (`html5VideoElement` == ID "stream", `html5VideoElement2` == ID "stream2"):

```js
function onAddRemoteStream(event) {
  if (event.transceiver.mid == remotemap["front"]) {
    frontstream.addTrack(event.track);
    html5VideoElement.srcObject = frontstream;
    html5VideoElement.play();
  }
  if (event.transceiver.mid == remotemap["audio"]) {
    frontstream.addTrack(event.track);
  }
  if (event.transceiver.mid == remotemap["surface"]) {
    surfacestream.addTrack(event.track);
    html5VideoElement2.srcObject = surfacestream;
    html5VideoElement2.play();
  }
}
```

`onAddRemoteStream` is the `onTrack` method for the RTCPeerConnection object. `remotemap` contains a mapping from track type to MID value, sent by the remote peer. `frontstream` and `surfacestream` are two (initially empty) MediaStream objects.

Weirdly enough, there are no exceptions or warnings with any browser, the first video element just stays empty and silent with Safari.

All outgoing streams (camera, audio, canvas) work on all three browsers.

Related issue: https://github.com/floe/surfacestreams/issues/6
Bountysource: https://app.bountysource.com/issues/105533187-html5-client-is-b0rken-on-safari

Any suggestions welcome!

UPDATE 01/23: So after almost one year, I can finally confirm that this was apparently a bug in Safari 14/15. It's now working, without any change in the relevant code bits, on Safari 16+.

Comment: P.S. Already tried with `muted="true"` as suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590138/i-need-to-assign-srcobject-to-itself-to-get-a-webrtc-video-stream-to-show-up - didn't make a difference, still only one stream in Safari. ️

Comment: And still no luck with Safari 15.2, even with adapter.js added on top :-/

Comment: Does it work if you initiate `play()` from a mouse click? IIRC, Safari will cancel audio and video contexts unless they were initiated from a handler for user events (click, button).

Comment: I think I never explicit tried that, will do. However, there are various WebRTC demos that only have the initial device access request as user interaction and still manage to immediately play audio and video... how?

Comment: Yes, I think what I'm talking about only applies to recording. Probably worth a test, though. Chromium, Firefox and Safari all have different rules for what sites are allowed to autoplay, though it wouldn't make sense that it would allow one stream to autoplay and not the other. Could it be an issue with the stream? Have you tried using the working stream for both?

Comment: I'm pretty sure by now that the reason for one stream working and the other not is the audio track (which only the non-working stream has). For the record, I also tried to set `muted=true` in Javascript as opposed to in HTML, and it still didn't make any difference.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the follow-up. So is it just an issue with the audio format inside the file? Have you tried removing the audio track or re-encoding it e.g. using ffmpeg

Comment: So after almost one year, I can finally confirm that this was apparently a bug in Safari 14/15. It's now working, without any change in the relevant code bits, on Safari 16+. 

Comment: haha appreciate the follow-up! Glad you got to the bottom of it!